# convert hashmap items into another object and return as a list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have this following code:

```
private List<Header> getHeadersList(HashMap<String, String> headersMap){
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> headerItem : headersMap.entrySet()) {
            Header header = new BasicHeader(headerItem.getKey(), headerItem.getValue());
            headers.add(header);
        }

        return headers;
    }
```

I wonder if there is a way of doing it using Java 8 stream library ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
headersMap.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e->new BasicHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Please, add some description.